# Trouble installing GCC 8.3

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying to install GCC so that I can get the Arduino IDE to work in my Chromebook's chroot so that I can program Adafruit's Trinket.  However, an attempts to install GCC have resulted in this error code:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... avr-unknown-none
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking for libatomic support... no
checking for libitm support... no
checking for libsanitizer support... no
checking for libvtv support... no
checking for libmpx support... no
checking for libhsail-rt support... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... yes
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 
$$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for the correct version of gmp.h... no
configure: error: Building GCC reqires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.  Try the --with-gmp, --with-mfpr and/or --with-mpc options to specify their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure.  See also http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html for additional info.  If you obtained GMP, MFPR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package, make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header files.  They may be located in separate packages.
```

Comment: You haven't told us what release of Ubuntu you have running, but why not `apt install` it?   https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gcc-8